# USB flash drive is not visible

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb

I've got my USB flash drive some kind of broken. When I insert it in my computer, it does not show up anywhere but ["Disks"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REQDQ.png) app. But even there there is nothing I can do with it.

I found some similar problems in the internet, they recommend using `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb` command to fix it, but when I do it I get following output

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: No medium found
```

Is there anything else that could solve my problem?

Comment: How old is the flash drive? If very old and extensively usd, it might be deteriorated. Is the problem persistent across reboots?

Comment: @spacelander it is about one y.o. i just remembered i've got this problem after i stuck on copying files to it. there never were such a problem before

Comment: does it show up in `lsblk`?

Comment: @spacelander no

Comment: what is the output of `dmesg | grep sdb`?

Comment: @spacelander 

[ 3366.862570] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk

[ 3571.534529] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk

[ 3654.097198] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk

[11776.961161] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk

Comment: that's good. What were you doing when it stoped working?

Comment: @spacelander i was trying to mount windows10 iso on it using unetbootin but the process stuck

Answer (score 0):

So your partition table is corrupt. You overwrite it with:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/<flashdrive> bs=512 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

as root; but be carefull to replace ‹flashdrive› above with the CORRECT drive, so you don't wipe your harddrive/SSD

Comment: unfortunately i have this output `dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb': No medium found
`

Comment: It's also possible that it broke and that's why unetbootin couldn't finish